# Can we do Idp initiated SSO using WSO2?

Tags: wso2, single-sign-on, saml

I am a newbie to WSO2 and just demonstrated a test SAML SSO using the link http://wso2.org/library/articles/2010/07/saml2-web-browser-based-sso-wso2-identity-server.
Now I want to know If we can also perform Idp initiated SSO using the same.
Please correct me If I am wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can. WSO2 SAML SSO implementation supports IDP initiated SSO. You can directly login to the WSO2 Identity Server at the first place and then you can access other resources in the SSO system.

Comment: Ok.Thanks. Just wondering if someone can suggest me some quick links for using WSO2 for custom authentication and OpenID.

Comment: Just got link from SureshAtt.Will try and update. Also would like to know custome authentication using wso2.

Comment: this blog will be helpful http://hasini-gunasinghe.blogspot.com/2011/08/carbon-authentication-framework.html